# Best way to handle product images on Magento 1.9.x?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

> Magento 1.9.1 and 1.9.4

I defined our front page image size to be 300 x 350 but some photos do not show that size (I guess based on the side ratios of the original product image?).

*It does not look good at all to have images of different sizes on the front page next to each other.* **How can we make it so that all images show the same size on the front page?**